# Virtual keyboard and physical keyboard, but different languages

Tags: x11, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I'd like to have active, at the same time, a virtual keyboard (I have installed [`onboard`](https://github.com/linuxmint/onboard)) and the physical keyboard of my notebook, but with different languages, say Russian (virtual) and English (physical), because I'm not familiar with the Russian layout and I need to peek the right key by visual inspection.

Unfortunately, afaict `onboard` uses the same layout/language (l/l) as the physical keyboard (I know how to install different l/l's and how to switch between them) and what I'd like to do cannot be done.

I suspect this (only one l/l active at once) could be a limitation of `X`, so my question has a few facets…

1. Is it possible to have two l/l active at the same time?
2. If it is possible, how can I accomplish it using `onboard`?
3. If `onboard` is unsuitable, is there a different virtual keyboard that provides this functionality?

Tia

Comment: Have you tried launching onboard explicitly specifying the desired layout via its -l option ( -l <LAYOUT>, --layout=<LAYOUT> Layout file (.onboard) or name ) ?

Answer (score 0):

The `onboard` [github page](https://github.com/linuxmint/onboard/blob/master/README) states:

> It has been designed with simplicity in mind and can be used right away
> without the need of any configuration, as it can read the keyboard layout
> from the X server.

So you should add additional keyboards to your setup and `onboard` will change as you move between them. It works for Debian 11/Xfce4.

There isn't much detail about your configuration though so it's hard to help you with that (which is actually another question).

If you are running Gnome (or Xfce4 for example) you could add the keyboard switcher to the panel configuration, select the distributions you're interested in, or go to Settings, Region and Language and inputs.

And that's it, `onboard` will follow the current layout.

Comment: Eduardo, that's _exactly_ the problem. The real and the virtual keyboards have the same layout, while I'd like to type English, or Italian, on the real one and peeking Cyrillic characters in the virtual.  I tried to express this problem of mine in my question, do you think I'd must edit it to make it more clear?

Comment: I still don't get the *peeking*. Either you type or you don't ... If you are only going to look at the keys maybe a simple solution like an image of the layout would be enough then?